# How to Use wildcard Regex Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad

Hello i am new in Regex of the Notepad++ Replace Option i have alot of files that start with

```
#include <right/someheader.h>
```

and i need to convert them to

```
#include "someheader.h"
```

without loosing the  someheader.h i did try using  this replace method:

```
#include <right/.*>
```

but it wont get the value of someheader.h it would simply replace it like this:

```
#include ".*"
```

Is it possible to make it work using Regex ? in Notpad++ i have seen this:
https://superuser.com/questions/637476/using-wildcard-search-replace-in-notepad
But i dont understand how to apply to my needs 
could anyone help? thanks

Comment: Try escaping the `/` [`#include <right\/.*>`](https://regex101.com/r/EfTCNT/1)

Comment: I use Notapad++ Replace function like here : https://superuser.com/questions/637476/using-wildcard-search-replace-in-notepad

Comment: Try search for [`<[^/]*/|>` and replace with `"`](https://regex101.com/r/JfQSGR/1/)

Comment: You may search for `#include <\Kright/(.*>)` and replace with `$1`

Comment: not working @Thefourthbird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the matches found by the regex:

```
<[^\/]*\/([^>]*)>
```

with

```
"$1"
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9wBm1U/1/)**

**Explanation:**

- `<` - matches a `<`
- `[^\/]*` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character except a `/`
- `\/` - matches a `/`
- `([^>]*)` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character except a `>` and stores it in Group 1
- `>` - matches a `>`

Before Replacement:

[image]

After Replacement:

[image]

Comment: This will lead in unexpected matches.

Comment: Tried to provide a bit generic solution. But we can include the word `right` in between to make it more specific like [`<right\/([^>]*)>`](https://regex101.com/r/9wBm1U/2)

Answer (score 0):

The regex to find what you're looking for would be this:

```
#include <right\/(.*)>
```

And you would want to replace it with:

```
#include "\1"
```

Anything inside brackets get stored in variables, which can be referenced with `\1`, `\2`, and so on. So this grabs anything after "right/", and stores it in the variable `\1`.